# error in load model robot in rviz

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi !
when i run this command :
~/wanderbot_ws/src$ roslaunch turtlebot_stage turtlebot_in_stage.launch

i have error for all links to load robot model in rviz : not transform

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245066/error-in-load-model-robot-in-rviz/) by [zakizadeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/27970/zakizadeh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 217 on 2016-10-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you probably have the fixed_frame set to `map` and no localization running.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0